# Observable that emits events distanciated exactly by a certain time interval

Tags: rxjs

I would like to create an Observable that emits every time interval, let's say every 100 ms.

If I try with `timer` method what I see is that the actual time interval between 2 events is always few milliseconds greater than 100. Same happens with `interval` method.

This is the snippet I use to measure intervals

```
const obsTime = Observable.timer(0,100).map(d => d + 1).take(30);

let t0 = Date.now();
let t1;
const timeIntervals = new Array<number>();
obsTime
.do(() => t1 = Date.now())
.do(() => timeIntervals.push(t1 - t0))
.do(() => t0 = t1)
.subscribe(null, null, () => console.log(JSON.stringify(timeIntervals)));
```

And this is the result I print

```
[2,105,103,101,103,106,102,105,103,106,105,103,105,105,105,105,106,105,102,101,105,105,104,102,105,103,106,102,101,105]
```

My question is: is it possible to obtain a series of events that emit exactly with 100ms of distance?

I do not think it is a matter of clock or speed of the CPU, since I am running on pretty new and powerful Mac, which is basically idle.

Comment: I think `Observable` has a method called `interval`

Comment: `JSON.stringify` maybe took time?

Comment: @Fussel: with `interval` I get the same result

Comment: @Yerkon: `stringify` is executed when the Observable completes and therefore I do not think it has an impact

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/certain-time-interval +-1/2 acurracy not 100 percent